# How to test for rotation amount before coming to a stop?

Tags: android, sprite, libgdx

I've got a sprite that rotates and when touch input is released, it rotates back to 0 degrees quickly. How can I get the rotation (degrees or otherwise) of the sprite just before the touch input is released?

I've looked and can't find any way to achieve, tough question to google.

EDIT Sorry for the latent response. Here is my code so far, will I be able to use the rPower variable to direct a projectile? Haven't gotten that far yet.

```
@Override
    public boolean touchDown(int x, int y, int pointer, int button) {

        if (Gdx.input.isTouched(0)) {
        cam.unproject(touchPoint.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0));
        }
        if (Gdx.input.isTouched(1)) {
            cam.unproject(touchPoint2.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0));
        }
    return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean touchDragged(int x, int y, int pointer) {

    if (Gdx.input.isTouched(0)) {
        cam.unproject(dragPoint.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0));
        dx = touchPoint.x - dragPoint.x;
        dy = touchPoint.y - dragPoint.y;
        throwerLowerArmSprite.setRotation(dx * 30);
    }
    if (Gdx.input.isTouched(1)){
        cam.unproject(dragPoint2.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0));
        d1x = dragPoint2.x - touchPoint2.x;
        d1y = dragPoint2.y - touchPoint2.y;
        throwerUpperArmSprite.setRotation(d1x * 30);

    }
    return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchUp(int x, int y, int pointer, int button) {
        if (!Gdx.input.isTouched(0)) {
        cam.unproject(releasePoint.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0));
        rPower = releasePoint.x - touchPoint.x;
        throwerLowerArmSprite.setRotation(0);
        }
        if (!Gdx.input.isTouched(1)) {
            cam.unproject(releasePoint2.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0));
            rPower = releasePoint2.x - touchPoint2.x;
            throwerUpperArmSprite.setRotation(0);
            }
        return true;
        }
```

Comment: Couldn't you keep track of the rotation with a variable? Update the variable as you rotate it.

Comment: Please show us some code or provide more details about how you are performing and tracking the rotations now.

Answer (score 0):

Your sprite rotates back to 0 degrees because of this in the `touchUp` method:

```
throwerLowerArmSprite.setRotation(0);
```

All the objects with `setRotation` methods also [have a `getRoatation()` method](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Sprite.html#getRotation%28%29).  So you can save the current rotation with:

```
float oldRotation = mySprite.getRotation();
```

Unrelated to the question, but you can simplify all of your input event callbacks.  You're mixing in the event polling methods to lookup data that the event callback already provides.  For example, your `touchDown` method could use its parameters like this:

```
public boolean touchDown(int x, int y, int pointer, int button) {
    if (pointer == 0) {
       cam.unproject(touchPoint.set(x, y, 0));
    } else if (pointer == 1) {
       cam.unproject(touchPoint2.set(x, y, 0));
    }
    return true;
}
```

This is even more useful in your `touchUp` method where the `pointer` parameter will tell you what `Gdx.input.isTouched` cannot (namely which pointer is the one that is no longer touching the screen).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, to clarify, I do want the sprite to rotate back to the starting position (0 deg). But I want to have the rotation amount, or the release point Vector2, after the user releases, so that I can take that release point to factor my projectile's direction/path.